# Art on Chol Hamoed

Tags: halacha, writing-printing, chol-hamoed, art

Most people say that you can't write on Chol Hamoed, but is it permissible to draw for pleasure as that is not considered "work"?

Comment: I think it depends how good you are. If it's professional level, then it would be considered maaseh uman.

Comment: General writing is permitted if needed for the festival. Professional writing, i.e. a scribe / calligraphy is not permitted. The same with art, I guess. If you feel like drawing a nice mural for your Sukkah (ok not this festival)  and it will enhance the festival and you're not professional then probably ok.

Comment: https://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Chol_HaMoed https://shulchanaruchharav.com/halacha/may-one-go-fishing-on-chol-hamoed/   See the sources. Especially #11 in the second link from Reb Moshe Feinstein regarding fishing for fun.  It's not easily allowable to do real melacha on chol hamoed unless you will derive actual benefit from it. I know many people go apple picking and don't eat the apples, but that is more of a question on them then a proof to allow all melachos.

Answer (score 1):

my bother called Lakewood Bais Horah (halacha hotline) and they permitted my sister whose not an artist to paint on canvass.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya Yehuda! Thanks for the answer.

Comment: was there any reason given,like it is a maaseh hedyot?

Answer (score 0):

From https://shulchanaruchharav.com/halacha/may-children-or-adults-draw-pictures-and-make-paintings-on-chol-hamoed/

> It is permitted for children or adults to draw amateur pictures, drawings, and paintings on Chol Hamoed as a fun activity for recreational and entertainment purposes. However, a professional picture or painting may not be done.

See there for the background and sources.

Answer (score 0):

[Shut Avnei Yashphe (1:110:2)](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=872&st=&pgnum=230) quotes "Gaon Echad" [=[R’ Elyashev z"l]](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=872&st=&pgnum=3) that children who have reached the age of "Chinuch" should not be allowed to draw or color on Chol Hamoed.